# Java 8 List<Map<String, Object>> to List<Map<String, Object>> group by key and count by value

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the following list of maps

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listBeforeGroup = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

    Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m1.put("company", "LG");
    m1.put("billType", "A");
    m1.put("billPeriod", "09-2018");

    Map<String, Object> m2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m2.put("company", "LG");
    m2.put("billType", "A");
    m2.put("billPeriod", "09-2018");

    Map<String, Object> m3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m3.put("company", "LG");
    m3.put("billType", "A");
    m3.put("billPeriod", "09-2018");

    Map<String, Object> m4 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m4.put("company", "LG");
    m4.put("billType", "B");
    m4.put("billPeriod", "01-2019");

    Map<String, Object> m5 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m5.put("company", "LG");
    m5.put("billType", "B");
    m5.put("billPeriod", "01-2019");

    Map<String, Object> m6 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m6.put("company", "Samsung");
    m6.put("billType", "A");
    m6.put("billPeriod", "10-2018");

    Map<String, Object> m7 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m7.put("company", "Samsung");
    m7.put("billType", "A");
    m7.put("billPeriod", "10-2018");

    Map<String, Object> m8 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    m8.put("company", "Samsung");
    m8.put("billType", "B");
    m8.put("billPeriod", "11-2018");

    listBeforeGroup.add(m1);listBeforeGroup.add(m2);
    listBeforeGroup.add(m3);listBeforeGroup.add(m4);
    listBeforeGroup.add(m5);listBeforeGroup.add(m6);
```

How do I get this output?

```
    //Desired Output - List<Map<String, Object>>
    //{company=LG, billType=A, billPeriod=09-2018, count=3}
    //{company=LG, billType=B, billPeriod=01-2019, count=2}
    //{company=Samsung, billType=A, billPeriod=10-2018, count=2}
    //{company=Samsung, billType=B, billPeriod=11-2018, count=1}
```

I tried this, using java 8 streams, but I can't get the desired output

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listAfterGroup = listBeforeGroup.stream().map(m -> m.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p - >  p.getValue()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And tried this, btw this solution gives a map but I don't want this

```
Map<Object, Long> listAfterGroup = listBeforeGroup.stream().flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,Collectors.counting()));
```

I want to group the maps by the key "billPeriod" for example, and count items by the values, then generate a new list of maps.

Comment: I would suggest a more OO approach here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class `Company` and then subsequent operations become much simpler.

```
class Company {
    String company;
    String billType;
    String billPeriod;

    public Company(String company, String billType, String billPeriod) {
        this.company = company;
        this.billType = billType;
        this.billPeriod = billPeriod;
    }

    // getters, setters, toString, etc
}
```

Initialize the list :

```
List<Company> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Company("LG", "A", "09-2018"));
list.add(new Company("LG", "A", "09-2018"));
list.add(new Company("LG", "A", "09-2018"));
list.add(new Company("LG", "B", "01-2019"));
list.add(new Company("LG", "B", "01-2019"));
list.add(new Company("Samsung", "A", "10-2018"));
list.add(new Company("Samsung", "A", "10-2018"));
list.add(new Company("Samsung", "B", "11-2018"));
```

Now for an example, you can group by company name :

```
Map<String, Long> map = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Company::getCompany, 
                              Collectors.mapping((Company c) -> c, Collectors.counting())));
```

Now it becomes much easier to perform other operations as you desire. Also, here instead of creating **8 maps** you end up dealing with just **1 list**.

Comment: that's a nice suggestion to introduce new object

Answer (score 2):

It's really difficult to grouping and counting a map because your map data will be changed after you increase your counter value. Therefore, you must save the original data of the map, and save your counter value to the another map. Join 2 maps after your counting process is complete.

```
Map<Map<String, Object>, Long> counterData = listBeforeGroup.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m, Collectors.counting()));

List<Map<String, Object>> listAfterGroup = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map<String, Object> m : counterData.keySet()) {
    Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>(m);
    newMap.put("count", counterData.get(m));
    listAfterGroup.add(newMap);
}
```

Update Java 8 approach, not easy to debug

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listAfterGroup = listBeforeGroup.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m, Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().map(e -> {
    Map<String, Object> newMap = e.getKey();
    newMap.put("count", e.getValue());
    return newMap;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I don't think your java8 solution is correct, have you tested it? in your code grouping groupingBy(m->m assumes two java maps with same set of keys and elements are equal, which is not true. So the result will be all counts=1

Comment: I have tested the java 8 solution, it works.
Output
    [{billType=A, count=3, company=LG, billPeriod=09-2018}, {billType=B, count=2, company=LG, billPeriod=01-2019}, {billType=A, count=1, company=Samsung, billPeriod=10-2018}]

Comment: then I like his solution +1

Answer (score 0):

My approach with java 8:

```
    Function<Map<String, Object>, String> createHashKey = map ->
                     map.values().stream()
                    .map(val -> String.valueOf(val))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());

    BinaryOperator<Map<String, Object>> mergeDuplicate = (map1, map2) -> {
        int incrementedCount = (int)map1.get("count") + 1;
        map1.put("count", incrementedCount);
        return map1;
    };

    List<Map<String, Object>> listAfterGroup = listBeforeGroup.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(createHashKey, el -> {
                        el.put("count", 1);
                        return el;
            },mergeDuplicate))
          .values().stream()
          .collect(toList());
```

Maybe not the most succinct solution but I think quite readable and easy to follow the logic of the code.

Comment: I have tested this approach, but it does not work.
Output:
[{billType=A, count=6, company=LG, billPeriod=09-2018}]

Comment: small mistake, just corrected the code - thanks for checking! ;]